# How to handle Node focus in JavaFX

Tags: javafx, focus

What `Event` is called in JavaFX, when a `Node` is focused?

I have `TextField`, which can be focused either by mouse (`setOnMouseClicked`) or by TAB key from other `Node` (here my problem comes in).

How can I handle the second focus possibility? Is there a way how to handle both at once?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can listen to the [`focused` property](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#focusedProperty--):

```
TextField tf = new TextField();
TextField tf2 = new TextField();

tf.focusedProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
    if (newValue) {
        System.out.println("Node 1: Mine!");
    }
});
tf2.focusedProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
    if (newValue) {
         System.out.println("Node 2: Mine!");
    }
});

Scene scene = new Scene(new VBox(tf, tf2), 300, 250);
```

If you change the focus, you can observe see the 2 `TextField` "arguing who's got the focus".